# Android browser blocks a web site?

Tags: android, browser

A user of my web site recently started getting this error -- "Data Connectivity Problem - The server failed to communicate. Try again later." -- when hitting my site from their Android phone.  The site works fine from my Android phone, and works fine from other devices.  The web logs show no evidence of his user ID hitting the site from an Android device, which suggests to me that his requests aren't even getting to my server.

I sent him a list of things to try and here was his response:

> Did all the things you suggested except the wifi and problem still existed. When I get the error message, it comes almost immediately after initiating going to the site--it doesn't seem like a time out. On a lark, I tried using Firefox (had been using the internet app from Google that comes preinstalled on the phone) and your site loaded just like it should.
>
> So I  went back to the internet app and cleared the cache, cookies, history--everything except form data and passwords--rebooted the phone, used the internet app to access your site and still got the error message. It's a mystery but at least it's operating correctly with Firefox. The problem must be with the internet app.

He's using an HTC Incredible on Verizon.  I was tempted to blame Verizon's network, but obviously that can't be the problem if it works for him with the Firefox browser.

Has anybody ever seen anything like this before?  What could be causing this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SSL, it may well be [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3334). It looks like it is caused by using a proxy server for SSL pages. It looks like the 'fix' is to turn off proxy settings.

In this case, the good news is, it's not your bug, and the bad news, you can't fix it. You might be be able to go with a lightweight WebView app that disables the proxy, if you want to go down the custom app route.

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello